# Not integrable although iterated integrals are equal

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How can I show that the function

$$f=\begin{cases} 0 & (x,y)=(0,0)\\\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} & \mbox{else}\end{cases}$$ is not Lebesgue-integrable, although the iterated integrals exist and are equal: 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}f(x,y)dydx=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}f(x,y)dxdy?$$

Comment: Normally, the way this happens is that, although the positive and negative parts of the function manage to cancel out in the iterated integrals, they are both infinite overall. So you want to compute the Lebesgue integral $\int_{[0,1]\times [0,1]} f^{+}\,dA$ and similarly the one for $f^{-}$. Recall that the definition of the Lebesgue integral is that $\int f = \int f^+ - \int f^-$, provided that at most one of the two subintegrals is infinite. The integrand has a clear rotational symmetry, which leads me to suspect that $f^+$ and $f^-$ will both be infinite if either is.

Comment: How does one show that the iterated integrals are equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. As $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, using polar coordinates we have,
$$
f(x,y) \sim \frac{\sin \theta\cos \theta}{r^2}
$$ which is **not integrable** as $r \to 0$.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will have a look on how to use polar coordinates..

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Hm how do I write it down formally? I thought about something like this, but it looks kind of clumsy to me:
$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r^2}d\theta = \infty$

I really have no clue what I have to do with the polar coordinates to be honest..can you give me one more hint what to do now?

Comment: Note that after the change of variable you end up with $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta\cos\theta \, d\theta\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{r}\, dr$ but $\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{r}\, dr$ is divergent.

Comment: Ok thank you. How does one obtain the form $\int_{0}^\pi \sin\theta \cos\theta d\theta \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{r} dr$ though?

Comment: By the change of variable $x=r\cos \theta,\,y=r\sin \theta$, the differential element $dx\,dy$ becomes $r\:dr\,d\theta$, the initial set of integration $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ becomes $[0,\pi]\times [0,1]$ and the function $f(x,y)$ becomes $\frac{\sin \theta\cos \theta}{r^2}$. Thus the initial integral becomes $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta\cos\theta \, d\theta\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{r}\, dr$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, got it now...

Comment: Ok I tried to write it all down by myself now and I got stuck at the point where I have to find the lower and upper limits of our integrals after changing variables. How does one obtain $[0,\pi]\times [0,1]$ I know how usual substitution works but somehow I do not get the results that you suggested..

Comment: @Sigma It is $[0,2\pi]\times [0,1]$, sorry for what I wrote in my comment above. But this does not change the conclusion $\int_0^1 \frac1r \:dr$ is still not convergent. Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations#2-Dimensional