# A converse version of Fubini's Theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, product-space, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Assume two $\sigma-$finite measure spaces $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{N},\nu)$. Consider a $\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{N}$-measurable function $f$, and we are interested in computing 
$$
\int f d\left(\mu \times \nu\right)
$$
where $\mu \times \nu$ is the product measure. I know the results of Fubini's theorem. Lets assume that one first observes that $f(x,y)\in L^{1}(\mu)$ for fixed $y$ and  $f(x,y)\in L^{1}(\nu)$ for fixed $x$. Then, he naively computes 
$$
\int \left[ \int f(x,y) d\mu(x) \right]d\nu(y)
$$
and
$$
\int \left[ \int f(x,y) d\nu(y) \right]d\mu(x)
$$
. and, he notices that the value of these two integral exist and are equal.

I have two questions:

1) Whether we can find a case as I described above?

2) Provided that we can find such an example, can we conclude that $f \in L^{1}(\mu \times \nu)$, and value of $
\int f d\left(\mu \times \nu\right)
$
equal to the $\int \left[ \int f(x,y) d\nu(y) \right]d\mu(x)=\int \left[ \int f(x,y) d\mu(x) \right]d\nu(y)$.

EDIT:
Answer: Assume the following function

$$
f=\begin{cases} 0 & (x,y)=(0,0)\\\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} & \mbox{else}\end{cases}
$$
It is exactly an example which satisfies the above conditions.

Comment: No. It is not sufficient that the iterated integrals exist and are equal. See e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812264/not-integrable-although-iterated-integrals-are-equal

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps a lot!